# JQ_CheckAllCheckBox 1.prop. 2.prop with each. Both are same?

Tags: jquery

I have this question because when I search "check all checkbox" on browser.

Many example done same like example-1.

example-1

```
$(".chkbx").each(function() {
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
    });
```

example-2

```
$(".chkbx").prop('checked', true);
```

what different between example-1 and example-2?

which is better ? / both are same ?

Thanks for viewing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$(".chkbx").prop('checked', true)`; is the best approach for your case

Sometimes `.each()` Isn't Necessary

Many jQuery methods implicitly iterate over the entire collection, applying their behavior to each matched element.the each method used to iterates over each matched element in the collection and do callback .

```
$(".chkbx").each( function( index, el ) {
     $(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

`$(".chkbx").prop('checked', true)`

Each .chkbx in the document will set the prop true to all matched elements.The .class selector selects all elements with the specific class.

Comment: I have this question because when I search "check all checkbox" on google.
Many example done same like example-1.
But I always do example-2.
Sorry, My English is not well. xd
Thanks for your recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

I think `$(".chkbx").prop('checked', true);` is better it's make the change using the class and you don't have to loop using `.each()` it will do that for you.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For given snippet, both are functionally achieves same. If more to be achieved on each checkbox element than obviously the `each()` comes into picture.